# $lookup Array of Objects in parent Array and append the results to each item of said Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, lookup

Considering the following document "Backpack", each `slots` is a piece of said backpack, and each slot has a `contents` describing various items and a count of them.

```
    {
        _id: "backpack",
        slots: [
            {
                slot: "left-pocket",
                contents: [
                    {
                        item: "pen",
                        count: 3
                    },
                    {
                        item: "pencil",
                        count: 2
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                slot: "right-pocket",
                contents: [
                    {
                        item: "bottle",
                        count: 1
                    },
                    {
                        item: "eraser",
                        count: 1
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

The `item` field is the `_id` of an item of another collection, e.g.:

```
    {
        _id: "pen",
        color: "red"
        (...)
    },
```

Same for pen, pencil, bottle, eraser, etc.

I want to make a `$lookup` so I can fill in the item's data, but I'm not finding a way of having the lookup's `as` be the same place as the item. That is:

```
    db.collection.aggregate({
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'items',
                localField: 'slots.contents.item',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'convertedItems', // <=== ISSUE
            },
        },
    })
```

Problem is that `as` being named `convertedItems` means the document gets an array of items in the root of the document called 'convertedItems', like this:

```
{
    _id: "backpack",
    slots: [ (...) ],
    convertedItems: [ (...) ]
}
```

**How can I tell `$lookup` to actually use the `localField` as the place to append the data?**

That is, make document become:

```
{
    _id: "backpack",
    slots: [
        {
            slot: "left-pocket",
            contents: [
                {
                    item: "pen", // <== NOTE
                    count: 3, // <== NOTE
                    _id: "pen",
                    color: "red"
                    (...)
                },
                {
                    item: "pencil", // <== NOTE
                    count: 2, // <== NOTE
                    _id: "pencil",
                    color: "blue"
                    (...)
                },
            ]
        },
    (...)
```

*Note:* At this point, if have entire data of item, doesn't matter if `item` property is kept, but `count` must remain.

I can't manually do `$addFields` with `arrayElemAt` because the number of items in `slots` is not fixed.

---

Extra Info: I'm using MongoAtlas Free so assume MongoDB 4.2+ (no need to unwind arrays for $lookup).

---

PS: I thought now of just leaving as root item (e.g. "convertedItems") and on the code that receives the API, when looping through the items, I do Array.find on the "convertedItems" per the the _id using the item. *I'll keep the question as I'm curious on how to do on MongoDB side*

Comment: unwind makes your collection explode, you can't specify in place of `as`, So you need to add additional stages like `addFields`, `filters` to get required o/p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use $lookup, there is a single query in the related collection for each document in the source pipeline, not a query per value in the source document.

If you want each item looked up separately, you'll need to unwind the arrays so each document in the pipeline contains a single item, do the lookup, and then group to rebuild the arrays.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$slots"},
  {$unwind: "$slots.contents"},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "items",
      localField: "slots.contents.item",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "convertedItems"
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$slots.slot",
      root: {$first: "$$ROOT"},
      items: {
        $push: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$slots.contents",
            {$arrayElemAt: ["$convertedItems", 0]}
          ]
      }},      
  }},
  {$addFields: {"root.slots.contents": "$items"}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$root"}},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      root: {$first: "$$ROOT"},
      slots: {$push: "$slots"}
  }},
  {$addFields: {"root.slots": "$slots"}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$root"}},
  {$project: { convertedItems: 0}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qxCfmtnphJW)

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than I thought :-O Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> unwind makes your collection explode, Also you can't specify in place of
>   'as', So you need to add additional stages like addFields, filters to
>   get required o/p

As I've commented, your requirement has a bit to do in order to match main doc's elements with `$lookup` result, maybe this can be easily done by code, but if it has to be done by query, using this query you'll be working on same no.of docs as what you've in collection quiet opposite to unwind as it would explode you docs when having nested arrays like what you've now, As in general this is a bit complex try to use `$match` as first stage to filter docs if needed for better performance. Additionally you can use `$explain` to get to know about your query performance.

**Query :**

```
db.Backpack.aggregate([
    /** lookup on items collection & get matched docs to items array */
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "items",
        localField: "slots.contents.item",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "items"
      }
    },
    /** Iterate on slots & contents & internally filter on items array to get matched doc for a content object &
     *  merge the objects back to respective objects to form the same structure */
    {
      $project: {
        slots: {
          $map: {
            input: "$slots",
            in: {
              $mergeObjects: [
                "$$this",
                {
                  contents: {
                    $map: {
                      input: "$$this.contents",
                      as: "c",
                      in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$c",
                          {
                            $let: {
                              vars: {
                                matchedItem: {
                                  $arrayElemAt: [
                                    {
                                      $filter: {
                                        input: "$items",
                                        as: "i",
                                        cond: {
                                          $eq: [
                                            "$$c.item",
                                            "$$i._id"
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      }
                                    },
                                    0
                                  ]
                                }
                              },
                              in: {
                                color: "$$matchedItem.color"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IGE8QZjBU8T)

Comment: The syntax became really hard to read and understand (compared to the other answer), at least to me, so that's the reason I didn't pick yours as the answer. Also seems that I'll need to manually add each new property that any item has been added by adding a new `in` like you did to the color, and manually add new backpack slots properties to the main `project`, so kinda makes maintenance harder (the other answer uses mergeobjects during the group so it keeps any other property I later add to any objects).

Comment: Nevertheless, It does work as expected for the current question in SO, and I have a whole new answer to study on how you did it, which is why I voted up. Thank you for taking your time to answer.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL : Yes which ever is comfortable can be picked :-) this answer also merging Objects so no need to individually pass fields to reform fields, This uses loops concept to avoid exploding collection with high no.of docs - unwinding on nested arrays can be an issue when your applications data grows overtime, if you can understand one loop rest all are same..